# How to parameterize these pretty hyperbolic (Amsler) surfaces?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, curvature

I've seen the attached images describing surfaces of negative curvature. I was wondering if there exist such surfaces with *constant* Gaussian negative curvature.

To this end, I attempted to model the surfaces by:
$$f(r,\theta)=A(r)\sin(n\theta)$$
And attempted to find $A(r)$ such that the surface would have a constant negative curvature, $K =const < 0$.

Unfortunately, the resulting differential equation is rather complex, and I not even sure it has a solution. So:

> 1. Is there a surface of constant negative Gaussian curvature, that can be described by $A(r)\sin(n\theta)$, for some finite range of $r$?
> 2. If not, are there other surfaces of constant negative $K$ that are similar to the images, and if so, what would be there
>      parameterization?

---

[image]

---

**Addendum**:

It looks like theses surfaces are similar to *Periodic Amsler surfaces*, that are [claimed](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.4442.pdf) to have constant Gaussian curvature. The paper in the link contains the following image, and it would be nice to understand how to parameterize them.
[image]

Comment: removed my answer but do see: demonstrations.wolfram.com/SurfacesOfRevolutionWithConstantGaussianCurvature/ , virtualmathmuseum.org/Surface/gallery_o.html#PseudosphericalSurfaces

Comment: Wo, seems these are more general than I expected, I can remove my answer if you want to as I doubt I will be able to prove anything. But the function below should have an analytically computable curvature I think so maybe it is possible to falsify.

Comment: @mathreadler - If you can, do delete your answer, as I'd like the question to appear in the 'unanswered' tab :)

Comment: Questions which do not have answers accepted by the poster seem to appear there. So this one would probably still appear there if there are unaccepted answers. However I can still delete the answer if you want me to.

Comment: @mathreadler your understanding of "unanswered" is correct.